# sql query to select 10 first rows ordered by sum/count

Tags: sql

```
ID  |   SSID   |   RSSI
1       abcd        -64
2       dasc        -70
3       ergc        -75
4       recg        -78
5       ertv        -84
6       ...         ...
7       ...         ...
8       ...         ...
9       ...         ...
```

This is sample data how my table `Scans_table` looks like, there are more than 300 rows, with these  5 `SSID` values but different `RSSI` values. I've created `Scans_table1`, with same columns as first table. What I'm trying to do is:

example ( take 5 first rows): SUM all `RSSI` values and COUNT `ID` where `SSID` = `abcd`, do it for 5 rows, then save SSID , RSSI to Scans_table1 ordered by sum(RSSI)/count(ID).

```
insert into Scans_table1 (SSID, RSSI) 
select SSID, sum(RSSI)/count(ID) 
from Scans_table 
where ID < 6 
order by sum(RSSI)/count(ID) 
desc limit ;
```

by far, with this query, I can save to `Scans_table1` the last of 5 rows, but the `sum(RSSI)/count(ID)` seems to work fine:

```
ID  |   SSID   |   RSSI
1       ertv        -80
```

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Isn't the COUNT if ID where `SSID = abcd` exactly 1 if the rows are repeating the values?

Comment: @GordonLinoff there are more rows with `SSID = abcd` that could have `ID` other than 1, for example `ID = 6`, then COUNT gives 2

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...